# How to get first 3 months of date column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I'd like to know how to get the first 3 month of data in table in sql server.
The table has `value` and `created_date` columns:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╗
║  value      created_date          ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╣
║  13         2013-08-20 11:30:00   ║
║   7         2013-08-20 04:30:00   ║
║   9         2013-08-21 11:30:00   ║
║  11         2013-08-22 11:30:00   ║
║  .                   .            ║
║  .                   .            ║
║  .                   .            ║
║  18         2016-10-03 11:30:00   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╝
```

When I use `DateADD(month, 3, getDate())`, it only return the next 3 monthss of the current date. So, I have no idea how to get them.

My actual problem is that I want to **calculate the average value of the first 3 months**. My plan is to get the minimum date from table and after that, get the next 3 months and calculate the average value.

Comment: Try using ROWNUM(), ORDER BY OVER the descending on CREATED_DATE and then get top(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
Select * from yourTable 
Where CreatedDate <= (Select DateAdd(Month, +3, Min(CreatedDate)) from YourTable)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is a great help although I have to change some for some requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `MS SQL Server 2012` or higher you can use [Windowing Functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1) to achieve this. You can use rows unbounded preceding and 2 following. Your code will look something like:

```
SELECT value,
       AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY CREATED_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
       AS '3_month_avg'
FROM <yourtable>
```

Comment: I think the keyword should be `UNBOUNDED` instead of `UNBOUND`. Am I right??

Comment: @nnt you care correct it should be Unbounded preceding that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you your starting point of reference to get the minimum date, that you can `date add` too or use as the lowerbound of a compound condition:

```
SELECT MIN(created_date) FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @minDate DATETIME;

SELECT @minDate = MIN(created_date) FROM YourTable;

SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE created_date <= DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @minDate);
```